# Gráfico con ionic Chart aparece en blanco

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ios, ionic, cordova

quería mostrar un gráfico en una aplicación realizada con ionic haciendo uso de Chart. He seguido los pasos obtenidos desde diferentes enlaces como por ejemplo este:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/08/using-charts-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/

Este es mi código:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

<!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  }
</script>-->

<!-- compiled css output -->
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<!--
  The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
-->
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">

  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<!--
  The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
  Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
  have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
-->
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
Declare chart: 

angular.module('starter', ['ionic','chart.js','starter.controllers','starter.services'])

...

 .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

...
```

And in the controllers.js:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.graph = {};
  $scope.graph.visible = false;

  $scope.showGraph = function(yesOrNo) {
    $scope.graph.visible = yesOrNo;
  }

  $scope.graph.data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];
  $scope.graph.labels = ['hoi', 'doei', 'hallo', 'hee', 'hoi', 'doei', 'hallo', 'hee'];
  $scope.graph.options = {
    animation: false
  };
  $scope.graph.series = ['Series']
  $scope.graph.legend = true;

})
```

Sin embargo, al hacer la prueba y cargar la pantalla tanto desde el emulador del dispositivo como desde el navegador el gráfico no se muestra, aparece en blanco y vacío. ¿Sabe alguien cuál podría ser el problema?

Comment: Viste en consola del navegador si aparece algun error,

Comment: @sioesi Si, aunque desde la consola no se visualiza ningún tipo de error. Pero tampoco se llega a mostrar el gráfico.